# Gabor filter application to list of images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

trying to apply a gabor filter to a list of images using skimage, and save the images in a directory. The filter gets applied fine, but I cant save the now transformed images. Here is my code

```
num = 0
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images("../Desktop/Positive"))
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = rgb2gray(image)  
    image = gabor(image, frequency=0.45, theta=.90)
    image = image=(np.array(image))
    image = gray2rgb(image)
    image = cv.fromarray(image)    
cv.SaveImage('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg', image)
```

The error I get is as follows:

---

error Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
14 cv.SaveImage('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg', image)

error: image.channels() == 1 || image.channels() == 3 || image.channels() == 4

---

Is this happening because its trying to save all channels in all images as one? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Is the indentiation of the last line correct? I mean, don't you want to save each image? | Also note that `cv2.imread` can fail, and you don't seem to account for that possibility.

Comment: What is the purpose of `image = cv.fromarray(image) `? Also I agree with @DanMašek, the indentation means you will only attempt to save the last image. Also, `cv.SaveImage` is legacy, you should use `cv2.imwrite`

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. You are correct, fixed the indentation. The image = cv.fromarray(image) was meant to transform the data to a format that was saveable, I see now that it is an array in any case and should not matter. When running the code now (with cv2.imwrite) it does not save the images, it creates one file with no information in it.

Comment: @Nord112 Please [edit] your question and add any corrections you've made. Note that `num` is set to 0, and then you never increment it, yet you use it in each iteration to generate an output filename.